# Software Deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, client

I have developed my C# desktop application using SQL Server 2019 as back end. I have used windows authentication mode. So is it necessary to install SQL Server 2019 on the client computer/machine ?

Or is there any option so that I should not install whole server on the client machine? Please clear me what I should install the Client machine.

Comment: I've never heard of 2019 R2 but there is Microsoft SQL Server 2019. With a traditional client server application, one does not install SQL Server on the client. The .NET framework includes the SQL Server client components you need (SqlClient) without a separate install.

Comment: Do you mean does the client machine need to have SQL Server install? Depends on your set up. If each user needs their own copy, then you may well be better off using LocalDB. If everyone is connecting the the same instance, then only the Server that the database is hosted on needs SQL Server installed.

Comment: But only one client need it. Is it necessary that client machine has a sql server.

Comment: Of course you need to install the SQL Server database engine on some machine, which could be a dedicated server or a designated client. All clients would connect to the same SQL Server instance.

Comment: SQL server is installed, it is establish the connection with the SQL server management studio, Configuration,services, running well, even permission is also given, but when we started the desktop application after installing it is always give the instance error, not established the connection etc.

Comment: Even I installed in other computer, this software is working perfectly.